# Android: Unable to parse JSON and input data to list view

Tags: android, json

Hi there I am trying to parse JSON from this url:

http://ec2-54-254-178-192.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/LockerManagementSystem/rest/lockerservice/lockers?type=small&type=medium&building=SIS&building=SOE/SOSS&status=working&level=2&level=3

and input this data into a listview
however, my listview displays nothing:

Here is my code:

```
  PopulateLockerList.java
  public class PopulateLockerList extends Activity {
// Used to make the URL to call for JSON data
String baseURL = "http://ec2-54-254-178-192.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/LockerManagementSystem/rest/lockerservice/lockers?type=small&type=medium&building=SIS&building=SOE/SOSS&status=working&level=2&level=3";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    lockerInfoList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    inputList = new ArrayList<String>();

    setContentView(R.layout.locker_list_main);

    final String displayLockerURL = baseURL;
    new MyAsyncTask().execute(displayLockerURL);
}

protected List<String> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    // Holds Key Value pairs from a JSON source
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray JsonlockerList = null;

    try {
        // Get the root JSONObject
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

        // Get the JSON object named data
        JSONObject dataJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");

        // Getting JSON Array node
        JsonlockerList = dataJSONObject.getJSONArray("data");
        // JsonlockerList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        // looping through All Lockers details
        for (int i = 0; i < JsonlockerList.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonLockerObject = JsonlockerList.getJSONObject(i);

            String lockerid = jsonLockerObject.getString("locker_id");

            // Cluster node is a JSON object
            JSONObject jsoncluster = jsonLockerObject
                    .getJSONObject("cluster");
            String cluster_id = jsoncluster.getString("cluster_id");

            // building node is a JSON object
            JSONObject jsonbuilding = jsoncluster.getJSONObject("building");
            String buildingID = jsonbuilding.getString("building_id");
            String buildingName = jsonbuilding.getString("building_name");

            String level = jsoncluster.getString("level");

            HashMap<String, String> lockerRow = new HashMap<String, String>();

            // / adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            lockerRow.put("lockerid", lockerid);
            lockerRow.put("cluster_id", cluster_id);
            lockerRow.put("buildingID", buildingID);
            lockerRow.put("buildingName", buildingName);
            lockerRow.put("level", level);

            // Adding lockerrow to lockerlist
            lockerInfoList.add(lockerRow);
        }// end of for loop

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnList;
}

protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> returnList) {

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < returnList.size(); i++) {

        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String,

        String>) returnList.get(i);

        // hm.put("txt", "Locker No : " + resultList.get(i));
        hm.put("lockerid", "Locker ID : " + hm.get("lockerid"));
        hm.put("cluster_id", "cluster_id : " + hm.get("cluster_id"));
        hm.put("buildingID", "buildingID : " + hm.get("buildingID"));
        hm.put("buildingName", "buildingName : " +

        hm.get("buildingName"));
        hm.put("level", "level : " + hm.get("level"));
        hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[0]));

        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "lockerid", "cluster_id", "buildingID",
            "buildingName", "level", "flag" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag, R.id.lockerid, R.id.cluster_id,
            R.id.buildingID, R.id.buildingName, R.id.level, R.id.flag };

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList,

    R.layout.locker_row, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.androidlist);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Please help me out

Comment: By not formatting your code properly before posting it you make it a lot harder for everyone to answer your question.

Comment: Your code isn't well formatted, it must be before posting, by the way jsonObject = new JSONObject(result); here what's the "result".

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Your done all correct except following lines

```
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

    // Getting JSON Array node
    JsonlockerList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
```

Just remove `JSONObject dataJSONObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");` and change to `JsonlockerList = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");` because **data** is `JSONArray` .

Comment: Hi I tried that but stil not working,are there any possible areas which I may be making the mistake at , because I have double check the code many times